# Creating a User Interface with Three Tabs for Lexical, Syntax, and Semantic Analysis in C Compiler Proje

Tags: c, compiler-errors, compiler-construction, gtk, gtk3

I have a small project to create a compiler for a language called "snake". I chose to do this project in C. I have already done the lexical, syntaxe, and semantic analysis. However, I have a problem with the user interface. I want to create three tabs: one for lexical analysis, one for syntaxe analysis, and one for semantic analysis. Does anyone know how I can do this?

I tried using gtk user interface and didn't know how to handle it

Comment: What user interface? A compiler is a batch program. It processes an input and produces an output.